# Search multiple array value and count the search result

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, logic

I have a bunch of array data from **$search** and **$data** variable like this:

```
$data = array(
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 13)
);

$search = array(
    array(1, 2),
    array(1, 3),
    array(6, 13),
    array(7, 13)
);

$result = array();
```

What I want to do is if each one pair *(EXAMPLE: 1 and 2)* of array data from **$search** match with all data inside **$data** variable it will count how many of data is match *(EXAMPLE: 1 and 2 have match on **$data[0]** and **$data[1]** so the result must be 2)*. And then save the count result into variable **$result** based on the key from **$search**.

Here's the result I was looking for:

```
$result = array(
    0 => 2,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 0
    3 => 1
);
```

And this is my code:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($search); $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<count($data); $j++) {
        if (count(array_intersect($search[$i], $data[$j])) > 1) {
            array_push($result[$i], "1");
        }
    }
}
```

As on my experiment above, if I save the count result to **$result** variable it just gives me a warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array. But if I try to save the count result using array_push to the **$search** variable, it will give me result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 13
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 13
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

The result is close to what I want, but still not like what I looking for. I really don't have an idea anymore how to do this.

Comment: the result should be `$result = array(
    0 => 2,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 1'
    3 => 1
);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error because `$result[$i]` is not an array, and array_push expects an array as input. I got it to work with the following code:

```
foreach($search as $index => $searchArray) {
    $result[$index] = 0;
    foreach($data as $dataArray) {
        if (count(array_intersect($searchArray, $dataArray)) > 1) {
            $result[$index]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it work very well, never cross in my mind it must use ++ operator :|

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($search as $key => $value) {
    $count = 0;
    if(in_array($value[0], $data[0]) && in_array($value[1], $data[0])){
        $count += 1;
    }
    if(in_array($value[0], $data[1]) && in_array($value[1], $data[1])){
        $count += 1;
    }
    $result[$key] = $count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the array value like this,

```
$result = array();
foreach($search as $k => $v){
    $result[$k] = array_count_values($data[0])[$v[0]] + array_count_values($data[1])[$v[1]];

}
print_r($result);
```